# PVC conduit into PVC box: Can I make it watertight when using a threaded fitting? Are sealing locknuts allowed?

Tags: electrical, pvc, conduit, nec

I have some 2" PVC conduit coming out of the ground and into a PVC box where it enters with a terminal adapter and held in place with a locknut. I intended to use a sealing locknut to keep the box watertight, but came across [this](http://forums.mikeholt.com/showthread.php?t=132070) discussion which has me worried the locknuts won't be allowed. Any advice? My AHJ uses the 2014 NEC.

Does that linked discussion apply to my situation? What is the correct/typical way to connect PVC conduit to a box outside (or are glued fittings generally always used)?

Comment: I have not had problems in the past using a TA in the bottom of a box using sealed coconuts plastic boxes if they have ko's always leak I usually will punch a hole in the bottom for drainage, according to that white paper it sounds like a TA with a Myers hub is also a no no and I have used these on top and side entry in the past and never been dinged. Hard to figure out how water would climb the threads on a bottom entry where a hole in the bottom is allowed. Just use a pvc nut and drill a hole what can they say then?

Answer (score 3):

Glued fittings are generally always used for PVC conduit to PVC boxes.

Most people also misunderstand the concept of exterior conduits and fuss about "keeping them watertight" when, in the code, they are *defined* as a **wet location.** And they will be, every time, no matter how watertight you make them - by condensation, if by no other means.

Comment: +1 for "no such thing as watertight"